# Apply formatting control characters (backspace and carriage return) to string, without needing recursion

Tags: python, regex, backspace, control-characters

What is the easiest way to "interpret" formatting control characters in a string, to show the results as if they were printed. For simplicity, I will assume there are no newlines in the string.

So for example,

```
>>> sys.stdout.write('foo\br')
```

shows `for`, therefore

`interpret('foo\br')` should be `'for'`

```
>>>sys.sdtout.write('foo\rbar')
```

shows `bar`, therefore

`interpret('foo\rbar')` should be `'bar'`

---

I can write a regular expression substitution here, but, in the case of `'\b'` replacement, it would have to be applied recursively until there are no more occurrences. It would be quite complex if done without recursion.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Complex, without recursion? You only have to look at each character once, from first to last. (You *must* start at the very beginning, because `foo\r\b\b\bix` discards `foo` -- right? -- and changes it to `fix`.)

Comment: Well, like I said, I can write a regex, compile it and use sub, but it would have to be recursive, which is cumbersome and inefficient.  I can also forget regular expressions and just go over the string myself.  I guess what I am asking is, is there some function that will do that for me, without having to do any of my own work :)

Comment: Your interpretation of `foo\rbar` is wrong, by the way. It does not really discard `foo`, it just gets overwritten *on screen*. The characters should remain in the input buffer.

Comment: @Jongware that is what I want, I want a function that will return "what is on the screen"

Comment: Mark: you say your string contains escaped control chars e.g. \\b or \\\\b. ***Please post example of that actual string in your question!*** Also note how raw-stringgs (r'...') get handled without escaping'; you might simply be copying-and-pasting a string that got printed to console with escaping; in which case you're solving a non-problem.

Comment: Do you care for ASCII escapes to? (I mean those for colors, bold & italics etc.)

Comment: Speaking for myself, I would be able to get this done faster just writing my own loop. It would most likely be more verbose than a regex, but for me it would be easier to write, easier to read, and easier to make changes should the need arise.

Comment: Also, if you need recursive regex (or any other more advanced regex features than what's included in Python's standard `re`), check out Matthew Barnett's [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

Comment: **Your call `re.compile('.\x08').sub('', 'ab\b\b')` is completely meaningless and does not do what you intend!** If you [read the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents), you'll see you should do `re.sub(pattern, repl, string)`. So in your case that's `re.sub('\b', '', 'ab\b\b')`. Kindly reverse your downvote. (I'll agree it's counterintuitive to other packages and languages that the search-string comes third. This bit me when I was learning Python too. Lesson learned: double-check your assumptions, reread the docs, type `help(re.sub)`.)

Comment: ...and there's nothing 'recursive' or escaped about 'ab\b\b'. That's just multiple (two) instances of your search pattern.

Comment: @Veedrac: wrong. His call to `re.sub()` was putting the string arg 2nd not 3rd. Which gives the wrong result like I posted.

Comment: @smci ...Third? There isn't a third argument in `SRE_Pattern.sub`.

Comment: @Veedrac: I don't appreciate the bickering at me, instead of asking him to clarify what he needed. Finally he tells us he wants to apply (not interpret) the Control-b character; repeatedly. I posted a working solution. (Yes, pat.sub has 2 args and re.sub has 3).

Comment: @smci I apologise if I came across as rude. I didn't mean to be.

Comment: @Veedrac: since I have now posted a fully correct answer (also I did all the repeated heavy lifting in getting OP to clarify what on earth they wanted), there is no reason not to remove your downvote.

Comment: @smci It seems you did not see [my message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878223/apply-formatting-control-characters-backspace-and-carriage-return-to-string-w?noredirect=1#comment40500712_25878298). Your solution does not work. You don't use `patc`, you use `str.replace` with a regular expression and the example string therefore comes out unchanged.

Comment: Fixed and working. (And in any case, the intent of the previous code was clear and correct)

Comment: @MarkGaleck What should `interpret("\b")` return?

Comment: Thank you all.  I am sorry I caused so much controversy here.  In any case, IMHO my original question was clear from the start.  The crucial wording is "shows" - I wanted code that would _return_ what the interpreter _shows_ on the screen.  I think this is very precise.  Yes it implies, double backspace etc, things like that.  But there is no need to spell that out.  It follows from the question.

Comment: @Veedrac it should return, the same thing as sys.stdout.write('\b') shows.

Comment: @MarkGaleck That depends on the terminal, though. Some will ignore it, others will go back to the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: after 30 minutes of asking for clarifications and an example string, we find the question is actually quite different: "How to ***repeatedly apply formatting control characters (backspace)*** to a Python string?"
In that case yes you apparently need to apply the regex/fn repeatedly until you stop getting matches.
SOLUTION:

```
import re

def repeated_re_sub(pattern, sub, s, flags=re.U):
    """Match-and-replace repeatedly until we run out of matches..."""
    patc = re.compile(pattern, flags)

    sold = ''
    while sold != s:
        sold = s
        print "patc=>%s<    sold=>%s<   s=>%s<" % (patc,sold,s)
        s = patc.sub(sub, sold)
        #print help(patc.sub)

    return s

print repeated_re_sub('[^\b]\b', '', 'abc\b\x08de\b\bfg')
#print repeated_re_sub('.\b', '', 'abcd\b\x08e\b\bfg')
```

---

[multiple previous answers, asking for clarifications and pointing out that both **`re.sub(...)`** or `string.replace(...)` could be used to solve the problem, non-recursively.]

Comment: @smci It's still broken for `"XXX\b\b\b"`. Your commented out expression seems to work in that case. That, though fails for `"\b"` and is `O(n²)` in the worst case. (Note that you have to @mention me if you want me to get an alert.)

Comment: @Veedrac: ok we agree the `repeated_re_sub('[^\b]\b'...` version works? b) it's faster than your version in the common case c) Noone cares about the defective case '\b', we could trivially fix that, but it's not worth compromising any performance for that.

Comment: @smci You also need to remove preceding `\b`s (so that `"\bX"` gets transformed to `"X"`) and you haven't dealt with the other half of the question (`\r`), so not really. Sorry :/.

Comment: @smci On second thought I'm not that sure about what to do with `"\b"`. I'll ask.

Comment: @Veedrac: wrong. `repeated_re_sub('[^\b]\b', '', "XXX\b\b\b")` works fine now. You didn't even check before you posted that. Really, your behavior is very aggravating and unconstructive.

Comment: @smci I suggest you reread my comment. I said that `"\bX"` doesn't work, not `"XXX\b\b\b"`. I also [asked the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878223/apply-formatting-control-characters-backspace-and-carriage-return-to-string-w/25878298?noredirect=1#comment40501845_25878223) what `"\b"` should result in, in case I misunderstood the goal.

Comment: @smci I do think that my original question is very well stated and precise, if you read it carefully it says, I want some routine that returns _what_would_be_printed_on_the_terminal.  It is exactly precise.

Comment: @Mark Galeck: no it was totally unclear. You asked for how to 'interpret' control chars. Without giving any example input or output. for 40 minutes! Nowhere did you say 'apply formatting control chars' until I decoded that was what you wanted and changed your title. Always always always give example input and output, where possible. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @smci I will respectfully disagree with you.  I said from the start, the function should return what is printed on the screen by sys.stdout.write .  This is clear.  You want to know what gets returned when some argument string is supplied.  Clear:  invoke sys.stdout.write and watch what shows on the screen.   That's what I said from the start

Comment: @Mark: a) it took like 40 minutes of us begging you nonstop to add sample input and output. As you surely know, standard Q&A guidelines are to **put those in the question to start with**. b) So absent any samples (which is terrible Q&A behavior), all you said was you wanted code to 'interpret' some strings... which comes down to how we 'interpret' whatever you might or might not have meant by 'interpret'... unreal... this is the semantic soup you get into for not giving a clear example in the first place. It's all on you. Next time I'll just downvote instead of bending over backwards to help.

Comment: @smci ??  Look at the original version of the question, it clearly shows the examples.

Comment: No, you did not post an example with repeated formatting characters, while still asking us cryptically about recursion. *('regex substitution would have to be applied recursively until no more occurrences...'*) And your title did not say ***'repeatedly apply formatting control characters...'*** until I decoded that was what you meant and inserted it. It only said 'interpret'. Which is very vague. I honestly didn't know what on earth you wanted.

Comment: @smci there is no need to mention anything about "repeated" anywhere.  It all follows from the passage in the original question:  obtain the terminal results of sys.stdout.write (...)
 So for example,
>>>sys.stdout.write('foo\br')
shows for, therefore

interpret('foo\br') should be 'for'

Comment: @smci I think we both stated our position enough times, so I will just drop it.  My position is " the original question was crystal clear".  Your position is "it was not clear".  Let's agree to disagree.  I won't argue anymore.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency doesn't matter, a simple stack would work fine:

```
string = "foo\rbar\rbash\rboo\b\bba\br"

res = []
for char in string:
    if char == "\r":
        res.clear()
    elif char == "\b":
        if res: del res[-1]
    else:
        res.append(char)

"".join(res)
#>>> 'bbr'
```

Otherwise, I think this is about as fast as you can hope for in complex cases:

```
string = "foo\rbar\rbash\rboo\b\bba\br"

try:
    string = string[string.rindex("\r")+1:]
except ValueError:
    pass

split_iter = iter(string.split("\b"))
res = list(next(split_iter, ''))
for part in split_iter:
    if res: del res[-1]
    res.extend(part)

"".join(res)
#>>> 'bbr'
```

Note that I haven't timed this.

Comment: I posted a non-recursive version `repeated_re_sub()`.

Answer (score 1):

Python's does not have any built-in or standard library module for doing this.
However if you only care for simple control characters like `\r`, `\b` and `\n` you can write a simple function to handle this:

```
def interpret(text):
    lines = []
    current_line = []
    for char in text:
        if char == '\n':
            lines.append(''.join(current_line))
            current_line = []
        elif char == '\r':
            current_line.clear()
            # del current_line[:]  # in old python versions
        elif char == '\b':
            del current_line[-1:]
        else:
            current_line.append(char)
    if current_line:
        lines.append(current_line)
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

You can extend the function handling any control character you want. For example you might want to ignore some control characters that don't get actually displayed in a terminal (e.g. the bell `\a`)